# how to make supervisord unkillable

Tags: linux, supervisord

I finished installation of supervisord on my centos6, it works also well. But I found I could use command "kill" to kill supervisord itself. I think this is wrong, I suppose supervisord is not killable, otherwise it can not guarantee the safe of other services which controlled by it. So how can I make supervisord is not killable please.

Comment: hi guys, if you know it, could you please give me a hint, it's really hard to find the result on google, please don't vote close the question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its clearly not programming related & belongs @ http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: You can't. The only thing you could do is run supervisor as another user, then it won't be killable by other uses; root can still kill it, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by no means possible to be done in a correct way lets say, though there is something that you could try and i think it will work. In theory only root can kill all proccesses and all other can always be killed by their owner. What you could actually try is to create a user that has an unbreakable password and get root to start a procceess using `su`. (root won't be asked to provide a password but 'su' will change to that user)

```
su newacct ksh -c "/home/newacct/bin/the_process_to_start.ksh and its parameters"
su - newacct ksh -c "/home/newacct/bin/the_process_to_start.ksh and its parameters"
```

The dash says that you should execute the .profile of that user. It depends if you want to or not. (You don't have to execute a script, but I assumed you were likely to in this example.)

This way, nobody but root can kill this process because nobody can become that user.

You might want to google how to make an undecryptable password in /etc/shadow. It's easy actually.

Comment: Or say when supervisord was killed, how does it relive immediately, the following process will relive, once you kill it:   root         1     0  0 14:21 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/supervisord

Comment: if it gets killed all child proccesses will crash with it i think, no time to save them by re-opening it...... still, i think...the main point is to keep it alive, and this is the only way i can think of....